# Exclude running firebase_messaging for flutter web

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to run firebase_messaging only on android and ios device, however if i put the firebase_messaging inside pubspec.yaml, and then run my flutter web it return

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messaging')
at new firebase_messaging_web.FirebaseMessagingWeb.new
```

And in order to run the flutter web, i must initialiseApp the firebase on web. Is there any way to run firebase_messaging only on android and ios

Comment: Try checking the value of `kIsWeb` (from: `package:flutter/foundation.dart`) for false everywhere in your code where you use Firebase messaging.

Comment: I haven't add anything yet for firebase messaging, only put at pubspec.yaml, however when run on flutter web it will return the error above, and when i declare the https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-messaging.js & https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js it will return FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app). my issue is that i dont want to use firebase messaging on web

Comment: What if you add initalization to `index.html` with `firebase.initializeApp` and then you don't use it on web?

Comment: actually i dont want to put that initialisation, because i dont want to generate any api key for the web version, is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure but I think it is not possible.

Comment: It looks like an flutter bug. I have the same thing so I am forced to use firestore initialization code inside html. :(